# Creating a function to read two text files and plot a graph from it

Tags: python, function, numpy, matplotlib, graph

I'm new here so bear with me.
I'm trying to create multiple graphs from varying text files of x,y arrays. This was the essentially the backbone of the code I was using to create a graph.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

filename = the_data_path

np.savetxt(filename, np.transpose([x,y]), delimiter=',', header= "x_values, y_values")
```

And these are the lines I used to create a graph from the arrays in the text file, so there are 2 data sets being compared.

```
line1 = np.genfromtxt("file1.txt", names = True, delimiter = ",")
plt.plot(line1["x_values"], line1["y_values"])
line2 = np.genfromtxt("file2.txt", names = True, delimiter = ",")
plt.plot(line2["x_values"], line2["y_values"])
plt.show()
```

Now I'm trying to create a function that will include the code from the second cell, to be able to call it more easily for the multiple other graphs from different data files. Any advice of which direction to head in would be great. I tried a handful of other things beginning with a `def my_plot():` but nothing has returned a graph.

Sorry this was so lengthy, thank you so much for your time in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to loop over all the files where you have stored the numpy arrays, you can define your function like this:

```
def my_plot():
  # n is the number of files you have containing numpy arrays
  for i in range(1,n):
    fname = f"file{i}.txt"
    line = np.genfromtxt(fname, names = True, delimiter = ",")
    plt.plot(line["x_values"], line["y_values"])
  
  #now plotting the graph
  plt.show()
```

Comment: Could you accept my answer if it worked for you? Thanks!

Comment: Yes so sorry I didn't know that was how it worked, first question of my own. Thank you again!